# How Do You Find A Non-Zero Slope Tangent Line To A Relative Min/Max?

Tags: calculus, functions

If you have a function with the equation $\frac {x^3} {3}-\frac {x^2} {2}-2x+1$. I know how to get the tangent line to that function quite simply.

However, I need to get a tangent line to either the relative minimum (which occurs at $2, \frac {-7} {3}$) or the relative maximum (which occurs at $(-1,\frac {13} {6})$ but the line needs to be tangent to some other place on the function and go through the relative minimum / maximum.

That is... I need a line tangent to the the function (can be tangent anywhere on the function) but goes through the relative minimum or maximum (I actually need 2 equations, one for each).

Thanks,
Heisenberg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line of slope $m$ that goes through point $(x_0,y_0)$ has the following equation:

$$ y = m(x-x_0) + y_0$$

The derivative of your function,

$$f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2} - 2x + 1$$

is,

$$ \frac{df}{dx} = x^2 - x - 2 = (x+1)(x-2) $$

So, your extrema are $(-2,-7/3)$ and $(-1,13/6)$

---

Okay, so you want a line with some arbitrary slope to go through your extrema. For this example, I will pick the point $(-1, 13/6)$. So, the equation for the line is:

$$ y = m(x + 1) + 13/6 $$

Considering our given function and its derivative, we have $y = f(x)$ and $m = f'(x)$ at some specific $x$ which we can solve for,

$$ \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2} - 2x + 1 = (x+1)(x-2)(x+1) + 13/6 $$

Solving for $x$, we get $x = 5/4$, so $f'(5/4) = -27/16$

The equation for your line then is:

$$ y = \frac{-27}{16} (x + 1) + \frac{13}{6} $$

I hope you can gather from this answer the methods to solve such a problem and how to do it for the other extrema.

Comment: Hello, I messed up and put a + between the first two terms rather than a negative and that is why we got different extrema - thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks, I changed my answer to reflect that. Please feel free to mark it as the accepted answer if it helps you.

Comment: Hello, I don't want a line with an 'arbitrary slope' that goes through the extrema, I want a line that is tangent to the function and goes to the extrema.

Comment: It is. The line is tangent to the function at $x = 5/4$$.